# Testing Notification on Android Emulator

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, notifications, expo, native

I am trying to test push notification using FCM on Android Emulator.
Some people say that testing push notification must require real device, but on the other hand there are some people who do not agree with this opinion.
So let me explain my problem with my codes.

This is my backend code. (Spring Boot)

```
FireBaseInitializer.java
package com.bongachat.configuration;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class FirebaseInitializer {
@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    try {
        FileInputStream serviceAccount =
                new FileInputStream("bongachat-363fa-firebase-adminsdk-8s38m-9604fa0dd5.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .build();

        if (FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options, "bongachat");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

This is notification handling service.

```
package com.bongachat.service;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.Message;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.Notification;

@Service
public class PushNotificationService {
public void sendPushNotification(String expoPushToken, String title, String body) {
    System.err.println("Send Push Notification called");
    System.err.println(expoPushToken);
    Message message = Message.builder()
    .setToken(expoPushToken)
    .setNotification(Notification.builder()
    .setTitle(title)
    .setBody(body)
    .build())
    .build();
    try {
    String response =         FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance("bongachat")).send(message);
    System.out.println("Successfully sent message: " + response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error sending message: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

And this is Frontend Code (React Native Expo)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import \* as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';

// For Redux
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { setExpoPushToken } from "../redux/userSlice";

const NotificationHandler = () =\> {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
// Request permissions for notifications
const registerForPushNotifications = async () =\> {
try {
const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
if (status === 'granted') {
const token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;

    dispatch(setExpoPushToken(token));
    console.log('Expo Push Token:', token);
    // Save the token to your server or use it to send notifications
  } else {
    console.log('Permission to receive notifications was denied');
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error getting push token:', error);
}

};

// Handle incoming notifications while the app is in the foreground
const handleForegroundNotification = (notification) =\> {
console.log('Notification received while app is in the foreground:', notification);
// You can customize how you handle the notification here
};

useEffect(() =\> {
registerForPushNotifications();

// Add listener for foreground notifications
const foregroundSubscription = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(handleForegroundNotification);

return () => {
  // Clean up the subscription when the component is unmounted
  foregroundSubscription.remove();
};

}, \[\]);

return (
\<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}\>
\<Text\>Push Notification Handling Example\</Text\>
{/\* Add your component UI here \*/}
\</View\>
);
};

export default NotificationHandler;
```

So in this application, I am getting an expoPushToken in development build and I sent it to backend and called the sendNotification function.
But the function gives me this error:
Send Push Notification called
ExponentPushToken[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]
Error sending message: The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token

So I am just wondering if it is a valid expo token or is it able to test push notification on android emulator?

I have no idea.
Please help me.
Thank you.